# Assumptions with D

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I want to give assumptions for the `D` function. Say I want to calculate $\frac{d|x|}{dx}$ for $x>0$, which is 1.

I write `D[Abs[x], x, Assumptions -> x > 0]` which gives

`D::optx: Unknown option Assumptions in D[Abs[x],x,Assumptions->x>0]. >>`
Why doesn't D take assumptions?

Comment: Because `Assumptions` is not a valid option for `D[]`; see `Options[D]`. What you want is `FullSimplify[D[Abs[x], x], x > 0]`.

Answer (score 7):

Many situations where assumptions play a role in differentiations can be equally or more clearly expressed by going back to the `Limit` defining the derivative in the first place. And `Limit` does take assumptions.

So for your example, instead of using `D`, you could write

```
Limit[(Abs[x + e] - Abs[x])/e, e -> 0, Assumptions -> x > 0]

(* ==> 1 *)
```

Here I've specified the assumption as an option. Another implicit assumption with `Limit` is that the small parameter `e` is taken to be real.